# Updating specific part of Arraylist string?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am making a program where the person inputs multiple values and the Arraylist stores it as a single string with option 1. Option two allows you to change a specific part of that string from "Complete" to "Incomplete" and vice-versa but only if the status part of the String is one of the two. I am getting the warning "Result of 'String.replace()' is ignored" and the part of the string isn't updating. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Array listObj = new Array();
        Scanner userinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        int arraysize = (listObj.list.size());

        int power = 1;
        while (power < 2) {
            System.out.println("To-Do List / What would you like to do?");
            System.out.println("1 = Add Task / 2 = Mark Task as Done / 3 = Remove Task / 4 = Edit Task / 5 = Display Tasks / 6 = Exit");
            int selection = userinput.nextInt();


            if (selection == 1) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= arraysize; i++) {
                    String title;
                    String date;
                    String status;
                    String description;
                    String id;

                    System.out.print("Enter Title: ");
                    title = userinput.next();
                    System.out.print("Enter Due Date: ");
                    date = userinput.next();
                    System.out.print("Enter Status (Complete or Incomplete): ");
                    status = userinput.next();
                    System.out.print("Enter Description: ");
                    description = userinput.next();
                    listObj.list.add(title + " " + date + " " + status + " " + description);
                    System.out.println();
                    listObj.list.forEach(System.out::println);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            if (selection == 2) {
                int idinput;
                System.out.println("Enter Project ID to Toggle Complete/Incomplete: ");
                idinput = (userinput.nextInt()-1);
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(listObj.list.get(idinput));
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("What is the status of this assignment?: ");
                String toggleselect = userinput.next();
                if (toggleselect.equals("Incomplete")) {
                    listObj.list.get(idinput).replace("Incomplete", "Complete");
                } else if (toggleselect.equals("Complete")) {
                    listObj.list.get(idinput).replace("Complete", "Incomplete");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Status is not Complete/Incomplete");
                }
                System.out.println();
                listObj.list.forEach(System.out::println);
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Array {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ArrayList<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}`your text`
```

Comment: The end of your quoted code looks like a copy/paste accident?: _"}`your text`"_

Answer (score 1):

```java
public String replace(char searchChar, char newChar)
```

demands a String to output to, as you can see by the return type. In this case use

```java
public E set(int index, E element)
```

from the ArrayList library,

with `E` return type being your ArrayList,

and `E element` being your call

```java
listObj.list.get(idinput).replace("Complete", "Incomplete");
```

So,

```java
listObj.list.get(idinput).replace("Complete", "Incomplete");
```

becomes

```java
listObj.list.set(idinput, listObj.list.get(idinput).replace("Complete", "Incomplete"));
```

Also, why are you creating a class called `Array` that just encapsulates an `ArrayList` in it?